# what is the ruby/rails/DRY/MVC way to display a color-coded matrix of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Up until now the MVC separation hasn't given me any big problems, but I have to admit the "right" ruby/rails/dry/mvc way to tackle color-coded display of tabular data has eluded me.

My app has a page that shows 7 columns (days of week) with 20 rows of data (20 different products) that ranges from 0-100 in each cell. Each value is an average of between 50-500 rows in the database.

So the table is displaying 7x20=140 separate 'average' calculations representing up to 500 rows of data each.

Because of the amount of data being shown to the user, we need to color code the cells based upon the value: <25 = red, 25..75 = yellow, >75 = green

our method that does the calculation is product.get_daily_average(date)

We're using HAML, btw.

The problem I have is figuring out where to put the code that specifies the color to apply to each cell...

...should there be if/then code to set the cell style (color) in the View? Is this a logical place for a Helper? Or should the model method that fetches the data "return" the html snippet with the color-code + data (instead of returning the value and letting the view handle the color)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally the type of thing that you would put in a helper method.

In your view you'd do something like this (sorry, don't know haml, this example is with erb)

```
<%= daily_average_cell(product) %>
```

And then in a helper

```
def daily_average_cell(product)
  value = product.get_daily_average
  color = daily_average_color(value) # probably just make this method right here in the same helper module
  content_tag(:td, value, :class => color)
end
```

Comment: ah... by using a helper to get the value once, then lookup the color style based on the value, I avoid the double-hit to get_daily_average(). nice!

Answer (score 0):

View helpers generally go into the file in `app/helpers` that corresponds to the controller rendering the views. For example (simplified for brevity):

`app/helpers/product_helper.rb`:

```
module ProductHelper
  def class_for_product_date(product, date)
    case product.get_daily_average(date)
    when 0..24
      "product_cell_red"
    when 25..75
      "product_cell_yellow"
    when 76..100
      "product_cell_green"
    else
      ""
    end
  end
end
```

`app/views/products/show.html.haml`:

```
@product.each do |product|
  %td{:class => class_for_product_date(product, date)}
    = product.get_daily_average(date)
```

Comment: this approach hits the get_daily_average() routine twice for each cell which in this case is a problem since it's a non-trivial dbase hit... which was one of the problems I was trying to avoid... if i specify the color in the view, as you do here, I need to calculate the same value twice.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. You could (1) output the whole thing in a helper, as in Aaron's answer; I personally don't like outputting (pseudo-)complex HTML from a helper, but it's a preference (and one many devs don't share). You could also (2) employ memoization in the model to cache the expensive database hits, or even (3) calculate `average` once in the view and then use it to (a) calculate the class via a helper and (b) output the value.